# when does LINQ outperforms ado.net

Tags: linq, ado.net

we know that linq is a layer built on top on the ado.net stack. it is very nice feature and makes database querying much better but linq is an additional layer and thus it adds some overhead to translate linq queries to sql queries and maps back the results while in ado.net we write the sql queries directly.

my question is when does linq performs faster than using the normal ado.net methods.

Comment: when the programmer does not know the intricacies of ado.net :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always be able to beat LINQ backed to a db with a stored procedure accessed from ADO and then either acted on directly or (if you must deal with objects) used to construct a an object with just the amount of data required for the task in hand.

However, LINQ lets us very quickly create a query which returns just that information needed for that task by returning anonymous objects.

To do the same with custom code per query would require either to not stop dealing with ADO at other layers (fraught in several ways) and/or to create a very large amount of objects that duplicate most of their functionality, but share no code.

So, while it can be beaten on performance, it can't be beaten in this case without a **lot** of rather repetitive code. And it can beat the more natural approach (to return entity objects with bloat we won't use) on performance.

Finally, even in cases where it doesn't win, it can still be faster to write, and clearer hot the operation relates to the way the entities are defined (this latter is the main reason I'm quite fond of it).

Answer (score 7):

When the time saved in writing all those queries in raw SQL and managing all the other translation etc allows you to spend more time on finding performance bottlenecks.

LINQ isn't about outperforming SQL. It's about making code simpler and clearer, so you can concentrate on more important aspects. There may occasionally be times where the natural LINQ expression of query ends up with faster SQL than you'd have come up with yourself - although there are plenty of times the opposite will happen, too. You should still look at the SQL being generated, and profile it accordingly.

Comment: +1: It's not always about the more efficient code.  It's about what's more efficient for the business.  Losing a few clock cycles while saving a noticeable amount of developer time is one way in which LINQ often "outperforms" ADO .NET.  (Not always, but often.)

Comment: thanks for the tips but this does not answer my question, im really looking for an example when linq performs better than ado.net

Comment: @Microgen: Better than the most highly tweaked and optimized plain ADO.NET code you could possibly write, with time being no factor? There may well not be such a case - but that's not what's important in reality.